# Concurrency in file transfer: is it worth it?

Tags: multithreading, networking, tcp, file-transfer

I am developing a software for an university project. One feature is the possibility to send an entire folder (not compressed) to another host in the LAN (not over the internet). Multiple data flows are allowed, for example an host can first send a folder, and while it is sending it can start sending a file, and both will be sent concurrently.

My idea is "ispired" by the FTP protocol: first on a control connection the "sender" will ask for ports to establish a data connection, than on the data connection the transfer will start. Everything is done using the TCP protocol.

I have a question about performance. Supposing I want to send a large folder, is it better to run a thread that will send files one by one, or to open N threads on N ports (on both sides of the connection, of course) and send multiple files concurrently?

I would have gone on the second option for sure: parallelism is cool. But then I saw that a cloud platform like Dropbox, when you update a folder, updates files one by one. And this raised the question: is in this application the parallelism better or not?

Just for completeness, I am programming over Windows and Linux, using C++11 and Boost::filesystem.